# Can I install ionic & cordova by offline method?

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to install Ionic from a corporate system. I have included the proxies everything, but my company firewall blocks "bplist-parser-0.1.1.tgz" file, so i get shasum check failed while running "npm install -g cordova" (because the file created is a almost an empty file). 
Is there any way to install ionic in one system & copy/mail the folders to another system. Please help me out. 
Thank in advance

Comment: Just ask the sysadmin to open that domain for some time :)

Comment: did any one got some answer, Im also facing the same issue